# Jqgrid colname height

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid like this:

[image]

So, I want that the 150px zone have 500px instead 150. I check with firebug:

[image]

Then in the css: Im watch this line:

```
       .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-bdiv{position:relative;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:auto;text-align:left;}
```

and I tried to give a height at this line for always (no matter what I do) the value is like firebug says: 150px. So I don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

For my astonishment the solution is in another place diferent to the css file.

You have to search this line on **jquery.jqGrid.js**

```
                    var p = $.extend(true,{
        url: "",
        height: 150,
        page: 1,
        rowNum: 20,
                    ...
```

And change the height of that (default height is 150px).

```
                    var p = $.extend(true,{
        url: "",
        height: 500,
        page: 1,
        rowNum: 20,
                    ...
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code if you want to change the height of all the row

```
 afterInsertRow: function(rowid, rowData, rowelem) {


$(this).jqGrid('setRowData', rowid, false, { height: '500px' });  
},
```

if you want to change the height based on some condition you can check it inside afterInsertRow  event function

Please note : Not sure this is a good / right way to do

Comment: thanks Kris. I found the solution in the jquery.jqGrid.js file :)